# "after update" trigger fires after insert in mySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 triggers on my table as defined...

```
DELIMITER $$
CRATE TRIGGER newRecordToHistory AFTER INSERT ON myTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (new.recordType = 1) THEN
        INSERT INTO myTableHistory
        (
            myTableId,
            someInformation,
            reason,
            mytimestamp,
            status
        )
        VALUES
        (
            new.myTableId,
            new.someInformation,
            new.reason,
            now(),
            'NEW'
        );
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and

```
DELIMITER $$
CRATE TRIGGER updateRecordToHistory AFTER UPDATE ON myTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (new.recordType = 1) THEN
        INSERT INTO myTableHistory
        (
            myTableId,
            someinformation,
            reason,
            mytimestamp,
            status
        )
        VALUES
        (
            new.myTableId,
            new.someInformation,
            new.reason,
            now(),
            'UPDATED'
        );
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I insert a new record into myTable, I get 2 records in myHistoryTable...

```
ID       someInformation     reason              mytimestamp          status
1        'This is new'       'Needed new record' 09/12/14 08:00:00    'NEW'
1        'This is new'       'Needed new record' 09/12/14 08:00:00    'UPDATED'
```

I also get a record in the table when I delete.  But my code handles inserting into the history table when I delete (so the user can specify the reason for deleting it) from myTable.

I would only expect only one record in myHistoryTable on insert and no extra records in the myHistoryTtable when I delete (other than the ones I put there manually).  Why does this happen?  And how can I avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: does your table `myTable` has something like on duplicate update in the table definition ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37511/1) with a small example where everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I cannot figure out what is going on.  I think I will just need to add the myHistoryTable record in code instead of using the trigger.  Nothing like "on duplicate update" in the table def.  Thanks for your help though.